# Repeating View with multiple OnClickListeners

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have got a Design that implements 3 very similar Views within a Fragment, with different User Input Values that are set by Minus (-) and Plus (+) Buttons.

 The XML part is done, but not the "Controller" part.

**Here is the View:**
[image]

I'm looking for a way to handle those OnClick events, that increase or decrease different values in a **Clean and Efficient** way.
I thought of maybe a CustomView but I don't know how to handle this specific case.
Anyone could help please?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these tutorials : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-compound-views-on-android--cms-22889 or https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-1-combining-existing-views/, they have the same compound view.